# GCM push notification DELAY

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I really stuck at here, when I make a push notification, the message was delay around 10 minutes. I check on logcat, only when the packageName is NOT LOCKED, the message will arrived directly. How I can control this ?

Any help is really appreciated.

Here is my logcat

**Logcat**

```
com.xxx.xxx D/MyGcmListenerService: From: 12345678
com.xxx.xxx D/MyGcmListenerService: Message: New Alert: #02 (ABC123)
com.xxx.xxx V/ContextImpl: ----- packageName = com.xxx.xxx is NOT LOCKED -----
```

**Manifest**

```
<!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- [END gcm_permission] -->

<!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.xxx.xxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->


    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".notification.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->



    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".notification.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->



    <service
        android:name=".notification.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

**ServerSide**

```
pushNotification("xxxxxxx", "#02(hello)");

function pushNotification($registatoin_ids, $message) {

        // prepare variables for push notification
        $message = array("message" => "$message", "time_to_live" => 10000, "collapse_key" => "sample", "delay_while_idle" => true);
        $registatoin_ids = array("$registatoin_ids");

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $GOOGLE_API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=XXXXXXXXXX',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        //print_r($headers);
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        // echo $result;
    }
```

**MyGcmListenerService**

```
    public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
    private static final String MyPREFERENCES = "xxxx";
    private static final String JOB_KEY = "xxxx";

    private String JobStatus;

    int countNotification = 0;


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        sendNotification(message);  
    }


    private void sendNotification(String message) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        JobStatus = sharedPreferences.getString(JOB_KEY, "");


        if (message.contains("#02")) {

             String submsg = message.substring(message.indexOf("(") + 1, message.indexOf(")"));

            Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            launch.setClass(getApplicationContext(), AnnouncementActivity.class);
            launch.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            launch.putExtra("message", submsg);
            startActivity(launch);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your code of GcmListenerService class and server side code for send data to gcm???

Comment: already update as request

Answer (score 3):

try to add '`priority' => 'high'` on your array $fields in php code

```
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
        'priority' => 'high'
    );
```

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

> High priority. GCM attempts to deliver high priority messages
>   immediately, allowing the GCM service to wake a sleeping device when
>   possible and open a network connection to your app server. Apps with
>   instant messaging, chat, or voice call alerts, for example, generally
>   need to open a network connection and make sure GCM delivers the
>   message to the device without delay. Set high priority only if the
>   message is time-critical and requires the user’s immediate
>   interaction, and beware that setting your messages to high priority
>   contributes more to battery drain compared to normal priority
>   messages.

Comment: why we need to set the priority ?
what is the limit of request per day ?
sorry for asking

Comment: After Google replaced C2DM with GCM, they took off all limits. so there is no limit of request pe day. the default of priority is 'normal' and you need to set the priority to 'high' when you want GCM service to wake a sleeping device when possible and open a network connection to your app server, in other words, if you want your notification come to your device as soon as possible when it's LOCKED just set the priority to 'high'

Comment: Now I get clear info, thanks for helping. Btw your method is work.

Comment: my rep+ is not enough, i will upvote once my rep is enough :)

Can I ask you 1 more question or we can contact through email.

Comment: of course, please tell me your question in here and i will answer it if i know :)

Comment: what is the best way to create an e-commerce app, means, in term of image handler, network, and UI ?

Comment: i dont have any experience in build e-commerce app on android. You can use library to make your work easier . for image handler you can use glide, for network (http transaction) you can use volley and for UI you can use clans, mastertab etc....

Comment: what do you mean by clans, mastertab ?

Comment: class is the name of library for floating action button. sorry not mastertab but materialtab , materialtab is the name of library for tab view......

Answer (score 0):

It's serverside issue

You can ask the server side person to change one of its property to `delay_while_idle=0`

This will solve your issue

Comment: is it related to delay_while_idle=0 ?

Comment: yes, 
when this flag is 1 it will wait untill the device wake up and when its 0 it will directly send to device.

Comment: delay_while_idle is deprecated. 
After Nov 15th 2016, it will be accepted by GCM, but ignored.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue that produces exactly these symptoms, thus is *could* be the cause of the behaviour you are seeing.

On cheaper wifi routers, the connection gets reset, so under these circumstances GCM only receives updates at the heartbeat interval.

TL;DR: try on a different wifi router, and see if you still have the same problem.

For more information see the following link:

https://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/

<quote / paste from above link>
The problem with these intervals is caused by network routers and mobile carriers, who disconnect idle socket connections after a few minutes of inactivity. Usually, this is more common with cheap home routers, whose manufacturers decided on a maximum lifespan of an idle socket connection, and terminate it to save resources. These routers can only handle a finite number of concurrent connections, and so this measure is taken to prevent overload. This results in terminated GCM sockets,

Comment: I think the modem I used is medium-end spec, not low quality.

Comment: Some cheap equipment is great quality, and some expensive equipment is poor quality -  its usually non-trivial to really know what is inside the gear you are using.  But for the sake of a quick 5 minute test of your app on a different Internet connection... At least then you know if this might be related to your issue or not... Plus it's a handy excuse for a walk to your neighbourhood wifi-coffee shop / or whatever your local equivalent might be :)